# Subsection numbering inconsistent between table of contents and actual subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I am experiencing a strange behavior where, in the table of contents, my subsections and subsubsections are in arabic, which is what I want.  However, in the actual subsections the labelling is alphabetic.

For example in the table of contents, I see this:

```
3.1 section name
```

But in the actual text, I see this:

```
A. section name
```

Below is an example:  what can I do to fix this?

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt,onecolumn,draftclsnofoot,]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection} 
{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section Name}
Section content
\subsection{Subsection Name}
Subsection content

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done, you're right, I should know better.

Comment: You can just remove that; I actually removed that line prior to your latest reply, as it does not have any impact on the sectioning issue I'm having.

Comment: When I compile the document I do not get any errors.

Comment: Ah, I see that.  That period only exists in the code I'd posted; it does not exist in my actual document.  I have removed it from the post. Not sure how it got there -- perhaps in my effort to indent/format it.  Apologies.

Comment: OK I cleaned up the comments and I now get the issue, I'll look, some ieeetran weirdness I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You can do the following but the only reason to use a publisher class such as IEEEtran is to follow publisher house style rules, so over-riding those rules is usually not recommended.

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt,onecolumn,draftclsnofoot,]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\let\thesubsectiondis\thesubsection
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection} 
{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section Name}
Section content
\subsection{Subsection Name}
Subsection content

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I had a feeling it had something to do with the document class but I could not, for the life of me, figure out the work around.  It was not so complicated, after all.